# Nav bar not scrolling on Chrome, but works fine on Internet Explorer, Safari, Mozilla, and Edge

Tags: css, google-chrome, navbar

The `navbar` on this website, http://cheresearch.engin.umich.edu/goldsmith/, mysteriously stopped working on Google Chrome. The Chrome web browser is fully updated. The `navbar` works fine on Safari, Mozilla, IE and Edge. I have cleared cookies and tried incognito mode on Chrome with no success.

The source code is:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="main-menu">
        <li><a href="#page-welcome">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page-experience">Research</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page-profile">Members</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page-portfolio">Publications</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page-contact">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page-experience1">Miscellaneous</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page-news">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. I have been searching far and wide for a fix the last month to no avail. Thank you.

Comment: what's the issue? it works fine in google chrome for me

Comment: It works fine for as well. Try clearing storage from application tab in dev tools.

Comment: Works fine here. Try deleting caches and history of your browser.
This might work.

Comment: Strange. It doesn't work on google chrome on any of my computers. I will take your advice.